# Maximizing the expectation of a polynomial function of iid random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, expectation

Let $f \colon \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function. Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $[0,1]$ and $X_1, \ldots , X_N$ be i.i.d. random variables on $\mathbb R$.

> **Question 1.** What is the maximum value of the expectation 
>   $$
> \mathbb E[\vert f(X_1, \ldots , X_N) \vert] = \int_{\mathbb [0,1]^N} \vert f(x_1, \ldots , x_N) \vert  d\mu(x_1) \ldots d\mu(x_N)
> $$
>   among all probability measures $\mu$ on $[0,1]$?

This question arises from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209895/expected-absolute-difference-between-two-iid-variables/2542224#2542224) and from [this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112459/apex-angle-of-a-triangle-as-a-random-variable/3112772#3112772) of Sangchul Lee which seem however tailored for specific functions $f$ and particularly for the case $N=2$.

I am very interested in the case $N\ge 3$; the function $f$ maybe be as smooth as needed (e.g. a polynomial). I have troubles in extending the (very elegant) variational approach of Sangchul Lee's to more variables, as no "bilinear form" is available.

After Nate Eldredge's comment, it is not restrictive to consider only a.c. measures. Furthermore, we can initially consider a somehow easier case, where $f$ is a polynomial (then maybe work by uniform approximation). In addition, thanks to a clever "random thought" due to Pierre PC (see comments below), we can start assuming symmetry of the integrand. All in all, the problem "boils down" to the following:

> **Question 1** (*easier version*): Maximize 
>   $$
> \int_{[0,1]^N} p(x_1, \ldots, x_N) g(x_1) g(x_2) \ldots g(x_N) dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_N,
> $$
>   among functions $g \ge 0$ such that $\int_0^1 g(s)\, ds = 1$, being $p \in \mathbb R[x_1, \ldots , x_N]$ a *symmetric* polynomial (of constant sign on [0,1]?).

Can this be handled by the [general Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Generalization_of_H%C3%B6lder's_inequality)?

---

Since the general case seems too hard, let me propose a toy model we can begin with. To me, it seems the difficult point is not the integrand (in view of the comment above general reduction arguments should lead to a very simple form of it) but rather the fact that $N \ge 3$ (in comparison with S. Lee's approach, which is tailored for $N=2$).

So here we go:

> **Question 2.** (baby version) What is the maximum value of the expectation 
>   $$
> \mathbb E[|(X-Y)(Y-Z)(Z-X)|] = \int_{[0,1]^3} |(X-Y)(Y-Z)(Z-X)| d\mu(X) d\mu(Y)d\mu(Z)
> $$
>   among all probability measures $\mu$ on $[0,1]$?

Comment: The maximum is equal to the maximum of $|f|$ is exists: take $\mu_j$ to be point masses at $x_j$ where $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ is the point of maximum of $|f|$. If $|f|$ has no maximum, then your expression also has no maximum.

Comment: @Alexandre This argument only works if the maximum is attained at a point which has all coordinates same because the points are i.i.d.

Comment: To the down-voter: could you please suggest what is going wrong in the question so that I can accordingly modify it? Thanks!

Comment: Random thought: the functional is weakly continuous in $\mu$, so you can sup over your favorite dense subset of $\mu$, e.g. a.c. measures suffice.  (2) it may help to uniformly approximate $|f|$ by simpler functions, e.g. polynomials.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for sharing your interesting "random thought" :-). However, is it really easier to restrict only to a.c. measures (this amounts to consider the functional I have written at the hand of my post)? Of course a great advantage is that we have now "two" functions $f,g$: is it possible to use Holder/other inequalities to find the maximum? I do not know. Concerning $f$, good point, let us replace $f$ with a polynomial $\tilde{f}$ (uniformly close to $f$).

Comment: @JosiahPark Interesting, thanks. How did you come up with that polynomial? And when is your candidate maximum value attained? Indeed, in the case $N=2$ we have Sangchul Lee's approach yielding that the optimal measure is a.c. with respect to Lebesgue. Can you use your Python code on more general polynomials? Thank you.

Comment: If, instead of polynomials, you look at indicator functions $f = 1_A$ for $A=A_1 \times \ldots \times A_n$ you get $\mathbb{E}[1_A(X)] =\Pi_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}_\mu (X \in A_i),$ which achieves its maximum $n^{-n}$ when $\mathbb{P}_\mu (X \in A_i ) = n^{-1}$ for all $i$. This suggests that, at least in this case, the maximum of $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ is $n^{-n} \sup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}f(x).$ I don't know if that helps.

Comment: @DavidHughes Mmm, interesting value, I had not found it. Can we use a "double" continuity approach (I mean wrt the measure and to the integrand) to reduce the problem to maximize $E[f(X)]$ where $f$ is an indicator function and formally prove that the max is the one you surmise? Thanks.

Comment: Actually what I said is only true if $A_i \neq A_j $ for $i \neq j$ and does not give the right answer in the linked cases...

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but here is another random thought. Because the expectation is symmetric, in fact it is the same to consider the expectation of $|f|$ or that of $x\mapsto\sum_\sigma |f(\sigma\cdot x)|/n!$, where $\sigma$ ranges over all permutations. So you need only consider symmetrical functions.

Comment: [Edited] In fact, if the maximum of the symmetrised function is M, then that method shows that the expectation is at least $n!/n^n\cdot M$, which coincides with David's case (where $M=1/n!$).

Comment: @PierrePC Interesting random thought! I see your point, you are suggesting that it is enough to solve the problem by consider only symmetric functions, am I right? But I am not following you in your second comment: which "method" are you referring to? D. Hughes' one? Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @Romeo About the reduction of the problem, yes. And it's not really a method, just consider $Sf$ the symmetrised function, find the point $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ maximising $Sf$, then set $\mu=\sum_i\delta_{x_i}/n$. You have a probability $n!/n^n$ to get a point that is a permutation of $x$.

Comment: For the baby version, E[(X-Y)(Y-Z)(Z-X)] would be more interesting.

Comment: Actually that cubic is not so good, since the integral will be identically zero by symmetry.

Comment: I might misunderstand the problem, but if you do not take the absolute value, for a polynomial of degree $n$ you have the expectation $$E\bigl[\sum_{|\alpha| < n} a_{\alpha} x^{\alpha}\bigr] = \sum_{|\alpha| < n} a_{\alpha} \, m_{\alpha_1} \cdots m_{\alpha_k}$$ in terms of the moments $m_i$, $0 \le i \le n$. So after you find the numbers $m_i$ that maximise the sum for the coefficients of the polynomial, you have a Hausdorff moment problem.

Comment: @student You are right, I have added the modulus. Thanks for the interesting connection to the Hausdorff moment problem, I did not know it and I'll certainly look into that.

Comment: For the baby version, the uniform distribution gives 1/30 (by integration, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%20Integrate%5B%28x-y%29%28y-z%29%28x-z%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2Cx%7D%2C%7Bz%2C0%2Cy%7D%5D), while the distribution evenly divided between 0, 1/2, 1 gives (6/27)(1/4)=1/18.

Comment: @MattF. So it seems that in the baby version the uniform distribution is not optimal. Hence also in the general version it might not be the maximizer. So probably there is no "canonical" maximizer and it depends on the polynomial itself? Interesting remark, thanks, I will think about that.

Comment: Hoping that Maple is not tricking me, numeric experiments indicate that the optimizer $\mu$ for the Baby Question is of the form $\mu = a \delta_0 + a \delta_1 + (1-2a) \nu$, where the number $a$ is approximately $0.27$ and the probability $\nu$ on $[0,1]$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue. Furthermore, it seems that the density of $\nu$ is a smooth function, whose graph is Gaussian-shaped, symmetric around $1/2$, where the maximum is attained. At the extremes of the interval, the density is small, maybe zero.

Comment: I believe that this Baby is a "terrible two".

Comment: Another numeric experiment indicates that if we square the integrand in the Baby Question, then the optimizer becomes $\mu = (\delta_0+\delta_{1/2}+\delta_1)/3$, that is, the distribution considered by @MattF. on a comment above.

Comment: @JairoBochi, a beta-version of your suggestion is $\mu=.326(\delta_0+\delta_1)+.348\beta(22.63,22.63)$, which gives an integral greater than 1/9.

Comment: @MattF. I see, beta distributions are good candidates. I didn't expected something so flat near the extremes, however...

Comment: @JairoBochi, I had an error in my calculations, which is why you expected something different; my new suggestion is in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 5):

We can in principle find the optimal first $n$ moments for a polynomial approximation of $f$. This reduces the problem to a truncated Hausdorff moment problem, for which solutions exist.

Let $f \colon [0,1]^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Approximate $|f|$ with the multivariate Bernstein polynomials of order $n$ (writing $f_{k_1\cdots k_d} = f(k_1/n, \ldots k_d/n)$ for short),

$$|f_n|(x) = \sum_{k_1 \cdots k_d} |f_{k_1\cdots k_d}| \prod_{i=1}^{d} \binom{n}{k_i} \, x_i^{k_i} (1-x_i)^{n-k_i} \;.$$

Let $S_k = E[X^k (1-X)^{n-k}]$. The expectation of the approximant is then

$$E[|f_n|(X)] = \sum_{k_1 \cdots k_d} |f_{k_1\cdots k_d}| \prod_{i=1}^{d} \binom{n}{k_i} \, S_{k_i} \;,$$

which should be maximal. The value of $S_{k}$ is a linear combination on the first $n$ moments $M$ of the resulting distribution. Expanding

$$S_k = \sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n-k}{r-k} (-1)^{r-k} \, M_r \;,$$

the expectation in terms of the moments is

$$E[|f_n|(X)] = \sum_{k_1 \cdots k_d} \sum_{r_1 \cdots r_d} |f_{k_1\cdots k_d}| \prod_{i=1}^{d} \binom{n}{r_i} \binom{r_i}{k_i} (-1)^{r_i-k_i} \, M_{r_i} \;.$$

The problem is hence the constrained multilinear optimisation

$$
\begin{aligned}
\max_{M_0 \cdots M_n} \;&\; \sum_{k_1 \cdots k_d} \sum_{r_1 \cdots r_d} |f_{k_1\cdots k_d}| \prod_{i=1}^{d} \binom{n}{r_i} \binom{r_i}{k_i} (-1)^{r_i-k_i} \, M_{r_i} \;, \\
\text{s.t.} \;&\; \sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n-k}{r-k} (-1)^{r-k} \, M_r \ge 0 \;, \\
&\; M_r \in [0,1] \;, \quad M_0 = 1 \;.
\end{aligned}
$$

To make the problem slightly more tractable, the relation between $S_k$ and $M_r$ can be inverted using the binomial partial sums,

$$M_r = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n-r}{k-r} \, S_k \;,$$

so that the optimisation becomes

$$
\begin{aligned}
\max_{S_0 \cdots S_n} \;&\; \sum_{k_1 \cdots k_d} |f_{k_1\cdots k_d}| \prod_{i=1}^{d} \binom{n}{k_i} \, S_{k_i} \;, \\
\text{s.t.} \;&\; \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n-r}{k-r} \, S_k \in [0,1] \;, \\
&\; \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \, S_k = 1 \;, \quad S_k \ge 0 \;.
\end{aligned}
$$

However, the first constraint is actually superfluous, as it is implied by the normalisation. Letting further $p_k = \binom{n}{k} S_k$, we have the optimisation problem in its most basic form,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\max_{p_0 \cdots p_n} \;&\; \sum_{k_1 \cdots k_d} |f_{k_1\cdots k_d}| \prod_{i=1}^{d} p_{k_i} \;, \\
\text{s.t.} \;&\; \sum_{k=0}^{n} p_k = 1 \;, \quad p_k \ge 0 \;.
\end{aligned}
$$

which is simply the maximum expectation of the discretised function $|f_{k_1 \cdots k_d}|$ from the discrete distribution $p$.

From a cursory Google search, multilinear optimisation appears difficult (but I have no idea, really). Nevertheless, it is a recipe for calculations: For the baby problem, I find (with $n = 50$) the expectation 0.0615760 and distribution $p$ as below.

[image: discrete distribution]

Comment: For the distribution in my answer, I found moments of {1/2, 37/90, 11/30, 113/330, 65/198, 457/1430, 449/1430, 121/390, 4/13, 26/85, 233/765, 1471/4845}, which are higher than your moments by {0, 0.011, 0.016, 0.019, 0.020, 0.021, 0.022, 0.022, 0.022, 0.023, 0.023, 0.024}.

Comment: For the moments of the optimisation, I get an expectation of 0.061419, which is slightly higher than 503582/8204625.

Comment: What about the polynomial integrand $(X-Y)^2(Y-Z)^2(X-Z)^2$? (Baby squared) My experiments indicate that in this case the maximum is attained at the discrete measure equidistributed at $0$, $1/2$, $1$.

Comment: @JairoBochi Same, with max expectation $\sim 0.0138889$. Same for powers of three. I wonder what the appearance of a continuous component depends on.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer**: This is a bit too much "abstract nonsense" for me to really consider it a satisfying answer to the question, but on the other hand the question is so general that I'm not sure how much better one can do.

Let's write $E=[0,1]$ and $P(E)$ for probability measures on $E$. Let $f : E^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and measurable. (Actually, this all holds for an arbitrary Polish space $E$.) I claim that you can write

$$\sup_{\mu \in P(E)}\int_{E^n} f\,d\mu^n = \lim_{k\to\infty}\sup_{(x_1,\ldots,x_k) \in E^k}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_k}f(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)}),$$

where $S_k$ is the set of permutations of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$, and $\mu^n$ is the $n$-fold product measure. As a sanity check, note that if $n=1$ then you can take $x_1=\ldots=x_k$ in the supremum to get $\sup f$. Not sure what to do with this for $n\ge 2$.

**Proof:** Fix $k \ge n$ for now. Then

$$\int_{E^n}f\,d\mu^n = \int_{E^k}f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,\mu^k(d(x_1,\ldots,x_k))$$

is a linear functional of $\mu^k$. The supremum of a linear functional over a convex set is the same as over its closed convex hull. Thus, if $C_k \subset P(E^k)$ denotes the closed (in total variation) convex hull of $\{\mu^k : \mu \in P(E)\}$, then

$$\sup_{\mu \in P(E)}\int_{E^n}f\,d\mu^n = \sup_{\nu \in C_k}\int_{E^k}f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,\nu(d(x_1,\ldots,x_k)).$$

Note that $C_k$ consists of all "mixtures of iid". Because De Finetti's theorem fails for finite exchangeable sequences, these "mixtures of iid" are not quite all exchangeable probability measures on $E^k$. However, if $P_e(E^k)$ denotes the set of exchangeable (invariant under permutations) probability measures on $E^k$, then a theorem of Diaconis-Freedman (Theorem 13 [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176994663)) says that for each $\eta \in P_e(E^k)$ there exists $\nu \in C_k$ such that the projections $\eta|_n$ and $\nu|_n$ onto the first $n$ coordinates satisfy $\|\eta|_n-\nu|_n\|_{TV} \le n(n-1)/2k$, with $\|\cdot\|_{TV}$ denoting total variation. It follows that

$$\left|\sup_{\mu \in P(E)}\int_{E^n}f\,d\mu^n - \sup_{\eta \in P_e(E^k)}\int_{E^k}f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,\eta(d(x_1,\ldots,x_k))\right| \le \|f\|_\infty n(n-1)/2k.$$

Next, for a given $\eta$ we can average over all permutations of coordinates in $f$ without changing the value of the integral. That is,

$$\sup_{\eta \in P_e(E^k)}\int_{E^k}f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,\eta(d(x_1,\ldots,x_k)) = \sup_{\eta \in P_e(E^k)}\int_{E^k}\hat{f}_k\,d\eta,$$

where the function $\hat{f}_k : E^k \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by

$$\hat{f}_k(x_1,\ldots,x_k) = \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_k}f(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)}).$$

We can then "un-symmetrize" the measures $\eta \in P_e(E^k)$ to reach a supremum over all probabilities on $E^k$:

$$\sup_{\eta \in P_e(E^k)}\int_{E^k}\hat{f}_k\,d\eta = \sup_{\eta \in P(E^k)}\int_{E^k}\hat{f}_k\,d\eta.$$

The right-hand side is simply $\sup \hat{f}_k$. Putting it all together gives

$$\sup_{\mu \in P(E)}\int_{E^n}f\,d\mu^n = \lim_{k\to\infty}\sup_{\eta \in P_e(E^k)}\int_{E^k}f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,\eta(d(x_1,\ldots,x_k)) = 
\lim_{k\to\infty}\sup \hat{f}_k,$$

which was the original claim above.

Comment: Gosh, thanks a lot for such an answer! I am very happy to read your contribution. I am not an expert in probability (I am not familiar with De Finetti or Diaconis-Friedman theorem) so I need sometime to study and understand your approach, which looks interesting. As a "concrete" example, may I ask you to kindly give a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3114400/maximum-expectation-of-volume-of-a-regular-tetrahedron-whose-angles-are-i-i-d) (where actually the whole story began)? Probably in that specific example your approach can yield the final answer... Thanks again!

Comment: '...says that for each $\eta \in P_e(E^k)$ there exists $\nu \in C_k$ ...' For your argument to work, shouldn't it be the other way around: for each $\nu \in C_k$ there exists $\eta \in P_e(E^k)$, and so on?

Comment: @Sinusx The other way around is immediate because $C_k \subset P_e(E^k)$.

Comment: @Romeo The more I reflect on this answer the more useless it seems. Very different things can happen in different examples, so you should not expect a very general answer. An important example from random matrix theory involves the "non-commutative entropy": Take $n=2$ and $f(x,y) = \log|x-y| - x^2 - y^2$. Then, over all probability measures $\mu$ on $[-1,1]$, the value of $\int_{[-1,1]^2}f(x,y)\mu(dx)\mu(dy)$ is maximized by the semicircle law $\mu(dx) = \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$. See e.g. Theorem 1.3 here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s004400050119

Comment: @Dan Thanks for your comments. I appreciate your contribution and I do not find it useless. Indeed, I decided to award the bounty to you, as you provided me a lot of new tools and theorem to think about. I hope the others who provided an answer do not mind: I acknowledge them too, of course, but your answer is more in the spirit of what I was looking for.

Comment: I am trying to understand this result. We can write $f(x_{\sigma(1)} \ldots x_{\sigma(n)})$ as an integral over $f$ and delta distributions at $x_{\sigma(1)} \ldots x_{\sigma(n)}$, $$\int \! f(x_1' \ldots x_n') \, \Bigl\{\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_k} \delta(x_1' - x_{\sigma(1)}) \cdots \delta(x_n' - x_{\sigma(n)}) \Bigr\} \, d^nx' \;.$$ So has this essentially shown that there is a maximising distribution, and that it can be approximated by sufficiently many point masses?

Comment: @Romeo notice that for this symmetric function $f(x,y)=\ln|x-y|-x^{2}-y^{2}$ and the semicircle measure $d\mu(x)$ we have $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x,y)d\mu(x)$ is independent of $y$. This correct "property" was explained by Sangchul Lee in his series of answers to previous problems. It seems to me that in general $n>2$ something similar should hold.

Comment: @Romeo, for example, following Sangchul Lee  if we are given symmetric $f(x,y,z)$, and assume the maximizer $d\mu(x)$ exists, then consider a perturbed maximizer $\mu \mapsto \mu+\varepsilon \delta_{s} - \varepsilon \delta_{t}$ and differentiate in $\varepsilon$ and make it zero. What condition you get on $d\mu$?

Comment: @PaataIvanishvili Nice observation about the semi-circle law! I now see the analogy with S. Lee's answer. I did want to try a similar approach but I thought that since we do not have any longer a "scalar product" that was not meaningful. Probably the correct way of writing it is by observing that some integrals has to be independent of the other variables... I'm going to try in a moment and I'll update if I have some news. Thanks!

Comment: If I did not make a mistake in my calculation then the right condition in case of n=3 for symmetric $f(x,y,z)$ is that $\int f(x,y,z) d\mu(x) d\mu(y)$ is independent of $z$. Can it help to solve the "baby" problem?

Comment: @student This is a good way to see it. Indeed, the function I called $\widehat{f}_k$ is the integral of $f$ with respect to $\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_k}\delta_{(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)})}$. In fact, this discrete measure is approximately equal to the product measure $$\frac{1}{k^n}\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_n=1}^k \delta_{(x_{i_1},\ldots,x_{i_n})} = \left( \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k \delta_{x_i}\right)^n$$ in the sense that the total variation distance between the two measures converges to zero as $k\to\infty$ with $n$ fixed, uniformly in the choices of $x_i$'s.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\mu = \mu_{\max}$ is a (Borel) probability measure on $[0,1]$ for which the following integral is maximized:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathcal{I}(\mu) := \iiint |(y-x)(z-y)(z-x)| d\mu(x)d\mu(y)d\mu(z) 
\end{equation}
Existence of $\mu_{\max}$ is relatively easy to prove.
We will prove the following

**Proposition:**
\begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{infinite}
\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\mu_{\max}([0,\epsilon])}{\epsilon} = + \infty.
\end{equation}
That is, **$\mu_{\max}$ has infinite density at $0$ and (by symmetry) also at $1$.**

Here are some **open questions**:

- Is $\mu_{\max}$ atomic at $0$ and $1$?
- Is $\mu_{\max}$ absolutely continuous elsewhere?

First, we prove a

**Lemma:** If $X$ is a random variable with measure $d\mathbb{P}$ and cdf $F(x)$ satisfying $F(x)\le cx$ on $x\in [0,1]$, and $p=F(\epsilon)$, then

\begin{equation}
\int_{[X \le \epsilon]} X  d\mathbb{P} \ge \frac{p^2}{2c} \, .
\end{equation}

Proof of Lemma: By a variant of the [well-known identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Formula_for_non-negative_random_variables) for a non-negative random variable $X$:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(X) = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x))dx,
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{align}
\int_{[X\le \epsilon]} X d\mathbb{P} 
&=   \int_0^\epsilon (p-F(x)) dx \\
&\ge \int_0^\epsilon \max(p-cx,0) dx \\
&\ge \int_0^{p/c} (p-cx) dx \\
&=   \frac{p^2}{2c}.
\end{align}
This proves the Lemma.

The proof of the Proposition \eqref{infinite} is by contradiction.
Let  $\mu=\mu_{\max}$ and let $F(x) := \mu([0,x])$ be the cumulative distribution function.
If the proposition does not hold, then there exists a finite $c \ge 1$ such that, for all $x\in [0,1]$,
\begin{equation}\tag{3}\label{linear}
F(x) \le cx .
\end{equation}
Note that $F(x)>0$ for every $x>0$, because if $F(x)=0$ for some $x>0$ then we can increase $I$ by replacing $\mu$ with $h_*\mu$, where $h$ is the affine map that sends $[x,1]$ onto $[0,1]$.

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be independent random variables distributed according to $\mu$;
let $\mathbb{P}$ denote the underlying probability.
Fix a constant $\gamma \in (0,1)$ such that the following event $\Gamma$ has probability at least $1/2$:
\begin{equation}\tag{4}\label{Gamma}
\Gamma := \big[ Y>\gamma, \ Z>\gamma, \text{ and } |Y-Z|>\gamma \big].
\end{equation}
Consider random variables $X_1 \le X_2 \le X_3$ obtained by ordering $X$, $Y$, $Z$;
so $X_1 = \min(X,Y,Z)$, for instance.
Fix a number $\epsilon$ in the range
\begin{equation}\tag{5}\label{epsilon}
0 < \epsilon < \frac{\gamma^2}{12c}.
\end{equation}
Define random variables $\tilde{X}_1 \le \tilde{X}_2 \le \tilde{X}_3$ by:
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
\tilde X_i := \begin{cases} X_i &\text{if } X_i > \epsilon, \\ 0 &\text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Finally, define 
\begin{align}
\Pi &:= (X_2-X_1)(X_3-X_1)(X_3-X_1) , \\
\tilde \Pi &:= (\tilde X_2- \tilde X_1)(\tilde X_3- \tilde X_1)(\tilde X_3- \tilde X_1) . \tag{7}
\end{align}
We claim that:
\begin{equation}\tag{8}\label{mainclaim}
\mathbb{E}(\Pi) < \mathbb{E}(\tilde \Pi) . 
\end{equation}
This means that $\mathcal{I}(\mu) < \mathcal{I}(\nu)$, where $\nu$ is the probability measure obtained from $\mu$ by crunching all the mass of the interval $[0,\epsilon]$ on the point $0$.
So the claim \eqref{mainclaim} implies that $\mu$ is not a maximizer,
and therefore it is sufficient to prove it in order to conclude \eqref{infinite}.

Note that $\tilde \Pi = \Pi$ whenever $X_1 > \epsilon$, and so:
\begin{equation}\tag{9}
\mathbb{E}(\tilde \Pi - \Pi) =  \int_{[X_1 \le \epsilon]} (\tilde \Pi - \Pi) d\mathbb{P} .
\end{equation}
On the other hand, $X_2 \le \epsilon$ implies $\tilde \Pi = 0$, 
so:
\begin{equation}\tag{10}\label{difference}
\mathbb{E}(\tilde \Pi - \Pi) =  - \int_{[X_2 \le \epsilon]}  \Pi d\mathbb{P} + \int_{[X_1 \le \epsilon < X_2]} (\tilde \Pi - \Pi) d\mathbb{P} =: -I_1 + I_2 . 
\end{equation}
Let us estimate the integrals $I_1$ and $I_2$.

Let 
\begin{equation}\tag{11}\label{p}
p := \mu([0,\epsilon]) = \mathbb{P}[X\le \epsilon].
\end{equation}
Then:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[X_2\le \epsilon] 
&= \mathbb{P}[X_2\le \epsilon < X_3] + \mathbb{P}[X_3\le \epsilon] \\
&= 3p^2(1-p) + p^3 \\
&\le 3p^2 \, . \tag{12}
\end{align}
On $[X_2 \le \epsilon]$ we have $\Pi \le X_2-X_1 \le X_2 \le \epsilon$.
Therefore we obtain the bound 
\begin{equation}\tag{13}\label{I1}
I_1 \le 3 \epsilon p^2 .
\end{equation}

Let us estimate $I_2 = \int_{[X_1 \le \epsilon < X_2]} (\tilde \Pi - \Pi) d\mathbb{P}$ from below.
Note that the integrand is non-negative, and so
\begin{equation}\tag{14}
I_2 \ge \int_{G} (\tilde \Pi - \Pi) d\mathbb{P}
\end{equation}
for any measurable set $G \subseteq [X_1 \le \epsilon < X_2]$.
We choose $G:= [X \le \epsilon] \cap \Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is as in \eqref{Gamma}.
Over $G$ we have:
\begin{align}
\tilde \Pi - \Pi 
&=   YZ |Y-Z| - (Y-X) (Z-X) |Y-Z| \\
&=   X(Y + Z - X) |Y-Z| \\ 
&\ge \gamma^2 X.\tag{15}
\end{align}
Therefore:
\begin{equation}\tag{16}
I_2  \ge \int_{G} (\tilde \Pi - \Pi) d\mathbb{P} \ge \gamma^2 \int_{[X \le \epsilon] \cap \Gamma} X  d\mathbb{P} = \gamma^2  \mathbb{P}(\Gamma) \int_{[X \le \epsilon]} X  d\mathbb{P}
\end{equation}
(since the random variable $X$ is independent from the event $\Gamma$).

Then by the lemma, $I_2 \ge \gamma^2 p^2/4c$ and therefore:
\begin{equation}\tag{17}
\mathbb{E}(\tilde \Pi - \Pi) = I_2 - I_1 \ge \left(\frac{\gamma^2}{4c} - 3 \epsilon \right) p^2 > 0,
\end{equation}
by our choice of $\epsilon$.
This proves the claim \eqref{mainclaim} and the Proposition.

Comment: I think an interesting question here is what property i) makes this $f$ (and its square and cube) have discontinuous parts, ii) makes $f$ have also a continuous part, but iii) makes e.g. $f = xyz$ have no point mass (but what seems like a funky distribution)? Edit: Actually I think it is not even clear that these are discontinuities.

Comment: FWIW the family of distributions I was thinking about is something like $\bigl(x^2 (1-x)^2 (1-2x)^2\bigr)^{-t}$ near $t=1/2$.

Comment: Another open question: does every subinterval of [0,1] have positive probability?

Answer (score 2):

We can attack the baby problem directly, as Jairo Bochi and I did jointly in the comments.

For instance, the distribution which is a mixture of:

- $3/5$ of a Bernoulli distribution with $p=1/2$
- $2/5$ of a Beta distribution with $\alpha=\beta=4$

yields an expectation equal to $503582/8204625$, or approximately $.0614$. This mixture of a discrete and a continuous distribution seems to be almost optimal.

Comment: Nice! This agrees much more with my experiments. As you say, your distribution seems almost optimal, but not exactly optimal. Indeed, the optimal distribution supported on a uniform mesh of 20 points yields an integral >.0615.

Comment: @JairoBochi, I figure what it lacks in optimality, it makes up for with round parameters and being exactly calculable.

Comment: I see. But is there any reason to believe that the true optimizer will have a Beta component?

Comment: Since it seems out of reach to find an exact solution for the baby problem (unless a miracle happens), I think that a more modest but still very nice problem would be to prove that any (the unique?) optimizing distribution is indeed a non-trivial mixture of discrete and continuous distributions.

Comment: The symmetric Beta distribution is one of the simplest distributions on the unit interval. Perhaps it maximizes a function of the order statistics like $E[X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}]/\sigma$; I'd be surprised if it's not the solution to some optimization.

Comment: So far I haven't been able to prove that the optimizer must contain a discrete (ie atomic) component. Maybe this is false, and what is going on is that the density tends to infinity at 0 and 1... I ask you the following: What if we combine two Beta distributions, one with parameters $>1$, another with parameters $<1$? Does this lead to an improvement?

Comment: @JairoBochi, I tried that, but the integrals are long enough that Mathematica stops without an answer, so I stopped too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete and elementary solution for the **Baby-squared problem**, that is, the Baby Problem with the integrand squared. 
The idea is to reformulate the problem in terms of moments, and originates from @student's answer.
By a linear change of coordinates, we can work on the interval $[-1,1]$ instead.
The result becomes:

> **Proposition**: For any Borel probability measure on $[-1,1]$, we have \begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{prop}  \iiint (y-x)^2 (z-y)^2 (z-x)^2 \, d\mu(x)d\mu(y)d\mu(z) \le \frac{8}{9}. \end{equation}
>   Equality holds if and only if 
>   \begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{three} \mu = \frac{\delta_{-1}+\delta_0+\delta_1}{3} . \end{equation}

**Remark:** As explained in other answers and comments, the maximizer $\mu$ for the original (un-squared) Baby Problem is certainly more complicated than \eqref{three}, and it seems to have a discrete and a continuous component.

**Lemma:**
If $X$ is any random variable on $[0,1]$, then:
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\mathbb{E}(X) \, \mathrm{Var}(X) \le \frac{4}{27} .
\end{equation}
Equality holds if and only if $X$ is Bernoulli with $\mathbb{P}[X=0] = 1/3$, $\mathbb{P}[X=1] = 2/3$.

**Proof of the lemma:**
There should be a direct argument, but here is a somewhat informal proof.
If $0<X<1$ with positive probability then we can deform the distribution of $X$ so that expectancy doesn't change and the variance increases.
Therefore expectancy times variance can only be maximized if $X$ is Bernoulli taking values $0$ or $1$. Then the lemma becomes a Calculus exercise.

**Proof of the proposition:**
Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $[-1,1]$.
For each positive integer $n$, let $M_n := \int x^n \, d\mu(x)$ denote the $n$-th moment of $\mu$.
Let $I$ denote the LHS of \eqref{prop}.
Computation shows that:
\begin{equation}\tag{4}\label{formula}
I = 12 M_1 M_2 M_3 - 6 M_1^2 M_4 - 6 M_3^2 + 6 M_2 M_4 - 6 M_2^3.
\end{equation}
[Curiosity: the fact that the expression on the RHS is nonnegative is a well-known general property of moments; actually the RHS is $6$ times the determinant of the positive-semidefinite Hankel quadratic form $Q(u_0,u_1,u_2) :=  \int (u_0+u_1 x + u_2 x^2)^2 \, d\mu(x)$.]
Note that:
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
2 M_1 M_2 M_3 \le M_1^2 M_2^2 + M_3^2 \le  M_1^2 M_4 + M_3^2 .
\end{equation}
This gives:
\begin{equation}\tag{6}\label{nice}
I \le 6 M_2 M_4 - 6 M_2^3.
\end{equation}

Consider the probability measure $\hat{\mu}:=(\mu+r_* \mu)/2$ on $[-1,1]$, where $r(x) := -x$; this measure is symmetric around $0$ (in the sense that $r_* \hat{\mu} = \hat{\mu}$).
The moments of $\hat{\mu}$ are:
\begin{equation}\tag{7}
\hat{M}_n = \begin{cases} M_n &\text{if $n$ is even,}\\ 0 &\text{if $n$ is odd.} \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Let $\hat{I}$ denotes integral on the LHS of \eqref{prop} with $\hat{\mu}$ in the place of $\mu$.
Then inequality \eqref{nice} can be rewritten as:
\begin{equation}\tag{8}
I \le \hat{I} \, .
\end{equation}
Furthermore, it's easy to check that if $I = \hat{I}$ then $\mu$ is symmetric around $0$ or $I=0$.

Therefore we can assume that $\mu = \hat{\mu}$, that is, $\mu$ is symmetric around $0$.
In this case,
\begin{equation}\tag{9}
I = 6 M_2 M_4 - 6 M_2^3 = 6 M_2 (M_4 -  M_2^2) = 6 \mathbb{E}(X^2) \mathrm{Var}(X^2) \, ,
\end{equation}
where $X$ is a random variable with distribution $\mu$.
By the lemma, $I \le 8/9$, with equality  if and only if $X^2$ is Bernoulli with $\mathbb{P}[X^2=0] = 1/3$ and $\mathbb{P}[X^2=1] = 2/3$. 
By symmetry, this means that $X$ is Bernoulli equidistributed on $\{-1,0,1\}$.
The proposition is proved.

Comment: I realized that for any $t \geq 2$, the integral $\iiint_{[-1,1|^3} |(x-y)(y-z)(x-z)|^t$ is maximized by the same measure $(\delta_{-1}+\delta_0+\delta_1)/3$. This follows from the fact that the integrand is maximized at the point $(-1,0,1)$.